# Miscalculation of upvotes on the tag-wiki pages?

Tags: support, up-votes, tag-wiki

I was trying some queries with the Stackexchange databrowser and there is one that shows you the [total upvotes you have received for a tag](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/137/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-towards-tag-specialist-badges).

For example for `jQuery` it tells me I have 254 upvotes. But on the [jQuery tag-wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=jquery&sort=info) it says:

> You were upvoted 426 times on non community-wiki answers with this tag.

I assume that this number is wrong and the one from the databrowser is correct as I don't have received a jQuery badge.

Comment: Or maybe it is just me? ;)

Comment: Yes the datadump is one month old at the moment see: http://odata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @waffles: Oh I have not noticed it... then why haven't I received a jQuery badge yet? Could it be also be related to the fact that http://stackoverflow.com/reputation shows a total reputation of `23,252` for me (~70 less then it is shown in my profile)? Maybe it is just a little off?

Comment: not sure, that is possibly a bug. need to investigate

Comment: Felix, tag-badges are one of those that can be delayed afair - wait a bit for it.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: Ok. It is not *that* important for me... I was just wondering. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the data explorer, [your reputation is 19,351](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/418/felix-klings-reputation). Since the last data dump was in July, i'm guessing the data used by it is simply out of date at the moment.

Comment: Ok. So it seems that up-votes on the wiki page is at least more correct than those on odata (obviously ;)). Then the badge thing seems to be bug, but this was not the question here... thank you!